# skiplocationchange browser backward issue. How to redirect to correct path

Tags: angular

I am using Stack Overflow to explore my knowledge. Yesterday while checking Angular questions I came across something called `skiplocationchange`.
I checked it and got that it is used to hide routes from URL.

I want to know how can I go back to previous route when click on browser's back button (this is same question asked in SO yesterday).

I have tried by pushing state to window.history but by doing this this starts showing full route in URL.

1. Is there is a way to do this
2. If not than what can be other way to hide route from url and while doing browser back button everything works fine

Below is reference link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-ex-w39hfp

Desired scenerio

1) home->course->angular

If now browser's back button is clicked than it should redirect to course route but this is not happening and it goes back to origin state

Comment: When you have `skipLocationChange: true`, When true, the app navigates without pushing a new state into history which means there is no way your browser knows about the previous/history of the urls visited so you can't go back to the previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you have `skipLocationChange: true`, When true, the app navigates
>   without pushing a new state into history.

Therefore, there is no way
your browser knows about the previous state of the app/ url visited so
you can't go back to the previous state using Browser's Back button which depends on the url's from history .

The only way of navigating back and forth is to have your own back button in the view and on click of it you can redirect user to another view.